# MASA in separable hyperfinite type II_1 factor

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Does the separable hyperfine type $II_1$ factor contain a copy of $L_\infty([0,1])$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots and lots of copies (as von Neumann algebras). In fact, any masa in any II$_1$-factor is isomorphic to $L^\infty[0,1]$.

This way more general result holds:

**Theorem.** Let $A$ be a diffuse separable abelian von Neumann algebra with
faithful normal trace $τ$. Then there exists a $∗$-isomorphism $θ:A\to L^∞[0, 1]$ such that
$$
τ(x) =\int_0^1θ(x)(t) dt,\qquad\qquad  x ∈ A.
$$

This can be found for instance as Theorem 3.5.2 in [*Finite von Neumann Algebras and Masas*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/finite-von-neumann-algebras-and-masas/CFF95F418A60971CBB6A867346EDAB97) by Sinclair & Smith.